# How can i get laravel to search from 2 columns when looking on a many to many relation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `Schools` table, I also have a `school_relations` table. The issue is I want to only show once relation between schools and not have to repeat it the other way round on the table of the relations.

Here is the migration:

```
Schema::create('school_relations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('school_id');
    $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('related_school_id');
    $table->foreign('related_school_id')->references('id')->on('schools');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Example in database:

| id | school_id | related_school_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 16 |
| 2 | 15 | 17 |
| 3 | 16 | 17 |

So, the school with id 15 is related to school with id 16, then the school with id 15 related to 17 and the last row the school with id 16 is related to 17.

As observed all the three are related to each other, but as of now I can only do this

```
$initialSchool  = \App\Models\School::find(15);
$relatedSchoolsInitial = $initialSchool->relatedSchools;
```

Which only works with showing 15 is related to 16 and 17 but when am in 17 or 16 I can't get to see that its related to 15 and the other one

What can I do so that I can query such a relation with only 3 entries to show relation between 15, 16 and 17

Answer (score 0):

Your **School** model can have the following two relations:

```
public function relatedTo()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        School::class, 'school_relations', 'school_id', 'related_school_id'
    );
}

public function relatedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        School::class, 'school_relations', 'related_school_id', 'school_id'
    );
}
```

You need a way to have a function called for example **related()** and this function can union those two relationships:

```
public function relatedSchools()
{
    $relatedTo = $this->relatedTo()->select(
        'schools.*',
        'school_relations.school_id as pivot_school_id',
        'school_relations.related_school_id as pivot_related_school_id');
    $relatedBy = $this->relatedBy()->select(
        'schools.*',
        'school_relations.school_id as pivot_school_id',
        'school_relations.related_school_id as pivot_related_school_id'
    );

    return $relatedTo->union($relatedBy);
}
```

In this case you can call:

```
$initialSchool = \App\Models\School::find(15);
$relatedSchoolsInitial = $initialSchool->relatedSchools;
```

And get all relations with other schools of school `15` where the id `15` is in either `school_id` or `related_school_id` in *school_relations* table.

Comment: Your response does not work flawless since in scenario where the third relation n is not shown it has an error in relation to cardinality but using your concept i went on to getting a working way.

Answer (score 0):

Prior on the schools model this is what i had

```
public function relatedSchools()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(School::class, 'school_relations', 'school_id', 'related_school_id');
    }
```

but made changes on the modal to have this;

```
    public function relatedTo()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            School::class, 'school_relations', 'school_id', 'related_school_id';
    }

    public function relatedBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            School::class, 'school_relations', 'related_school_id', 'school_id'
        );
    }
```

On the controller had this;

```
 $initialSchool = \App\Models\School::find(17);
    $relatedToSearch = $initialSchool->relatedTo()->pluck('schools.id')->toArray();
    $relatedBySearch = $initialSchool->relatedBy()->pluck('schools.id')->toArray();

    // Merge the arrays of related school IDs
    $allRelatedSchools = array_merge($relatedToSearch, $relatedBySearch);

    //removing any duplicate
    $allRelatedSchools = array_unique($allRelatedSchools);

    //Retrieve id and school name
    $relatedSchools = \App\Models\School::whereIn('id', $allRelatedSchools)->get(['id', 'name']);
```

So now it works exactly the way i wanted.